# alpha style citation in embedded system

Tags: bibliographies, labels

Is it possible to have alpha style like citations, without a .bib file? Writing

```
See \cite{AB18}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{AB18}
Alice, Bob. \emph{Our paper}. 2018.

\end{thebibliography}
```

what I want is to read labels instead of numbers:

See [AB18].

References

[AB18] Alice, Bob. Our paper. 2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply the desired label in the optional argument to `\bibitem`. Make sure to specify the longest label in the argument to `thebibliography`, otherwise the indentation will be off.

Note further that the label shown in citations (*AB18*, *A11*) is completely independent of the internal entry key/cite key (`alice`, `alicebob`).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
See \cite{alice}.

\begin{thebibliography}{AB18}
\bibitem[A11]{alice}
Alice. \emph{My paper}. 2011.

\bibitem[AB18]{alicebob}
Alice, Bob. \emph{Our paper}. 2018.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: "See [A11]" in text and "[A11]" and "[AB18]" in the bibliography.]